# Не работает jquery.Не пойму в чем проблема

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
 <script>// Hide Header on on scroll down
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
    
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });
    
    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);
    
    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;
        
        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $('footer').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('footer').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
            }
        }
        
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
 </script>
```

Мне нужно чтобы заработал второй script. Он работает только когда я удаляю первый (`material.min.js`). А так работает только первый. **JQuery** подключен.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вы действительно где-то ранее подключили jQuery, то код рабочий. Уточните, что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Конкретно не работает второй script. По скрипту видно что он по свайпу вверх должен скрывать footer, а по свайпу вниз показывать.Он это делает только когда я удаляю первый script (внешний material.min.js)

Comment: Это все итак поняли. Проведите дебаг, посмотрите, какие ошибки в консоли. Не работает скрипт, это не проблема, это нежелание искать причину. Настрадамусов здесь нет, угадать вашу проблему никто не сможет.